# Null Pointer Exception while trying to print via Comm Port, in JDK 1.8

Tags: java

Null Pointer Exception while trying to print via Comm Port, in JDK 1.8. We are migrating from JDK 1.7 to 1.8. (1.8u66)
we are using javax.comm jar. Copied the 'win32com.dll' inside JDK 1.8 / bin folder.
Below is the full exception trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name can't be null
    at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:191)
    at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:277)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkDelete(SecurityManager.java:1007)
    at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:89)
```

Application code goes here:

```
public class PrintClient { 
    protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 
    public PrintClient() {
        try { 
            CommDriver driver = (CommDriver) Class.forName("com.sun.comm.Win32Driver").newInstance(); 
            driver.initialize(); 
            CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM1"); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    } 
}
```

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you migrating to `8u66` [released in 2015](https://www.java.com/download/help/release_dates.html)? It's a very old version.

Comment: Show us the code.  "Name can't be null" doesn't sound like a dll problem to me.

Comment: Thanks @Robert for highlighting...i've done the edit. 
Error happens at line 6 while trying to get PortIdentifier("COM1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Java can't find the provided  driver location which causes for a null pointer exception saying that "Caught java.lang.NullPointerException: name can't be null while loading driver com.sun.comm.Win32Driver".

So Firstly, please make sure that you've already installed the given driver or else please follow the below installation steps to install it.

1. Download and unpack the `javacomm20-win32.zip` file.
2. Place the `win32com.dll` in `<jdk>\jre\bin` directory (or the `\jre\bin` subdirectory of your current J2SDK directory.)
3. Place the `comm.jar` in `<jdk>\jre\lib\ext`.
4. Place the `javax.comm.properties` in `<jdk>\jre\lib`.
5. Do not alter the `CLASSPATH`.

Please refer this [oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2105954/name-cant-be-null-while-loading-driver-com-sun-comm-win32driver) for further details.

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks Prathibha, it helped...working fine now.

Comment: It's nice to hear @Abuthahir. If this fixed your issue please mark it as the correct answer. So other with the same issue can easily detect the correct answer.